# How to fill a recently deleted face with the mirror modifier on

Tags: faces, mirror

I used the mirror modifier with clipping, now I wanted to restart with something and I deleted all the faces, now I searched on google how to fill an face, and it said select the vertices around the space u want to fill and then use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Now I can't do this since I use the mirror modifier and only have three lines instead of four.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: you can select the 3 edges and press F but maybe show a screenshot?

Comment: @moonboots I'll try and it says that my image (screenshot) is too large

Comment: @moonboots it worked thanks!